# Is the Visual Studio Notification flag part of a font set

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone here happen to know if the flag that appears in the title bar of visual studio to alert users of new notifications (see the illustration below) is part of a font family (ie along the lines of wingdings) which gives it that blue roll over effect when one rolls one's mouse over it.

I have been experimenting with adding additional buttons to the Title Bar (I'm using Actipro's RibbonWindow and adjusting the WindowChrome) and I can see that using text with a certain style added will give the correct effect. Now I'm just trying to establish if the flag symbol that is used in visual studio is readily available and if so where.  For example I know that using a capital o as the content of a button and setting the font to Wingdings will produce a flag, but not the one that Visual Studio uses.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is a path. In VS 2015 it is defined as "F1M14,0L0,0 7,14 9,14 6,8 14,0 14,0z M11.586,1L5.293,7.293 4.94,7.645 1.618,1 11.586,1"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wonderful.  Thank you so much for taking the trouble to answer.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest how did you get the live visual tree to run against visual studio itself.  I've only just got the enterprise edition and am finding my way around how to use useful tools like this.

Comment: I started two instances of VS 2015 and used Debug - Attach to process... from the second instance to the first one.

Comment: That you Sergey, great to know how to do that.