# What steps do I need to follow to use the Live Visual Tree on a program other than visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

This is really a follow on from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784933/is-the-visual-studio-notification-flag-part-of-a-font-set) question.

I have started up Visual studio (as an administrator) and then started up a second instance of visual studio and been able to observe a live visual tree of the second instance by attaching to that second instance.

Flushed with success and having discovered something new in amongst the tools that visual studio offers I wanted to see if the same could be done with other programs (specifically at least to start with I was interested in outlook as I wanted to try and find the property for the question mark glyph on the window title bar).

I can certainly attach to the running `Outlook.exe` but unlike when I attach to `Visual studio` the `Live Visual Tree` does not pop up automatically.

Am I doing something wrong? or is an incorrect sequence or would this approach not work with something like outlook?

Comment: No version of Outlook that I'm aware of uses WPF to composite its UI, and so far as I'm aware, the Live Visual Tree tool works exclusively with WPF based apps.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  In all my new found knowledge of using attch process to view the visual tree of other programs, that small but rather fundamental point (that outlook and indeed the rest of Office) is not wpf based rather escaped my attention.  Plus 1 for pointing out what an idiot I can be on Monday mornings.   Guess I'll have to figure out another way to find out if the question mark is actually a glyph or not.